# Python RegEx running past limiter

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
EUID=000000;GTIME=503551082,+0;KEY=034534D9D1644C0B27404283D04B78B9B31BA143D80ABDF8781FE45D8246B92;IV=9B3112343D80ABDF8781FE45D8246B92;GPOS=+00000.0000,+00000.0000;
```

I would like to extract each value between an `=` and a `;`.

I've tried the following:
d_block = (the string above)

```
import re    
re_euid = re.search('EUID=(.*);', d_block)
    euid = re_euid.group(1)

    re_gtime = re.search('GTIME=(.*),', d_block)
    gtime = re_gtime.group(1)

    re_tzone = re.search(',(.*);', gtime)
    tzone = re_tzone.group(1)

    re_key = re.search('KEY=(.*);', d_block)
    key = re_key.group(1).upper()

    re_iv = re.search('IV=(.*);', d_block)
    iv = re_iv.group(1)

    re_gpos = re.search('GPOS=(.*);', d_block)
    gpos = re_gtime.group(1)
```

For some reason...Each value is returning more than it should. It's not stopping at the `;` as I'd like.

Example of current data returned for euid:

```
000000;GTIME=503551082,+0;KEY=0061ECAD9D1644C0B27404283D04B78B9B31BA143D80ABDF8781FE45D8246B92;IV=9B31BA143D80ABDF8781FE45D8246B92;GPOS=+00000.0000,+00000.0000
```

Which is the whole string except for the `EUID=`.

Comment: Briefly: you need `?`.

Comment: You need `*` to be non-greedy. Try a `?` after the `.*` or change it to accept any character except `;`

Comment: Just 2 cents, (1) why use regex here if you can just split by `;` as you are treating every part different anyway (2) i think the point and efficiency of the regex gets lost if you keep applying 6 different patterns to the same string if you could do this with 1 pattern. I honestly would go with (1) :)

Comment: And I'd just do `res = dict(re.findall(r'([A-Z]+)=(.*?);', d_block))` and then properly parse each object (such as turning `GTIME`'s value into a `datetime` object).

Comment: Can you add an example that would work for this that uses only one pattern? A start to finish for the findall()

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote above. It even creates a tidy dictionary for you. Post-processing the matching strings is up to you.